# nibbleToString Exception non-exhaustive patterns in function

Tags: haskell, exception

I'm new at Haskell and I've tried to write a function that takes a List of Booleans and then converts it into the corresponding List of Ints, ie nibbleToString [True,False,False,True] should evaluate to 1001. This is what my code looks like:

```
nibbleToString :: [Bool] -> [Int]
nibbletoString [] = []
nibbleToString (x:xs)
    | x == True = [1] ++ nibbleToString xs
    | otherwise = [0] ++ nibbleToString xs
```

And it compiles, but when I execute it I get

```
[1,0,0,1*** Exception: klausurprep.hs:(79,1)-(81,42): Non-exhaustive patterns in function nibbleToString
```

And I don't know why. In my understanding, there are three possible Input categories: empty Lists, Lists that begin with a true and lists that begin with a false and I have accounted for all three of them, so I can't see why my patterns are non-exhaustive. Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: it's just a typo - `nibbletoString [] = []` uses a lowercase `t` so it's not recognised as being part of the same function. Replace it with an uppercase `T` and this is fine (although it could be simplified somewhat - eg `x == True` can be replaced with just `x`)

Comment: I recommend to keep warnings enabled: GHC can report such typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nibbletoString` should be `nibbleToString`,

Appending a single value to a list `[a] ++ as` is called consing: `a : as`, you can write it

```
nibbleToString :: [Bool] -> [Int]
nibbleToString []         = []
nibbleToString (True :xs) = 1:nibbleToString xs
nibbleToString (False:xs) = 0:nibbleToString xs
```

The whole definition can be written `nibbleToString = map fromBool`. `map` applies a function `fromBool` to each element of the list

```
-- map = fmap @[]
map :: (a -> b) -> ([a] -> [b])
map f []     = []
map f (a:as) = f a:map f as

-- fromBool = fromEnum @Bool
fromBool :: Bool -> Int
fromBool True  = 1
fromBool False = 0
```

Comment: If it doesn't cause confusion: There are a couple of other ways of writing a `map` 1) list comprehension `nibbleToString bools = [ fromBool bool | bool <- bools ]` 2) `do`-notation `nibbleToString bools = do bool <- bools; return (fromBool bool)`